# How many different focal lengths and apertures does a typical lens correction profile in Lightroom consist of?

Tags: lightroom, lens-correction

Due to different distortion in lenses at different apertures and focal lengths different corrections have to be applied under different conditions when using Lightroom lens correction. I guess this is done by taking a photos of meshes and grids under various conditions.

Is a typical lens profile in Lightroom a result of only a few measurements or are there corrections for a large number of conditions? If not, does Lightroom interpolate to get something close to a correct correction?

Answer (score 2):

You can use as reference the document [Calibration Chart Shooting Guide for the Adobe Lens Profile Creator](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/lensprofile_creator/lensprofile_creator_chartshooting_qs.pdf). In the advanced setup you can see that it is possible to shot data for several aperture and several focal length.
Of course if the data set is not complete lightroom engine will interpolate the missing data.
For the supported lens supplied with lightroom engine I also suppose that the data set are almost complete and accurate.

Comment: What do you mean by almost complete. A zoom range is continuous and the EXIF-data represents zoom state down to the millimeter. A complete data set would therefore be data for every single integer of the focal length in millimeter between the lowest and highest focal length. That seems to be to complex to me.

Comment: With almost I mean discrete sampling. I can suppose that the various brand will support within a complete dataset.

Comment: Ok, but this still does not quantify the number of different images that make up a lens correction. The guide just states how many images that is recommended to use in order to create a basic and an advanced profile. That does not have to be the numbers used in a typical lens profile made by Adobe.

Comment: Yes it is true. An empirical way to understand it is (having the access to the lens profile integrated in lightroom) to weight the dimension of datafile and compare it with one "handmade", but of course is empirical way.